# getPropertyValue doesn't wok in IE9?

Tags: javascript, cross-browser, internet-explorer-9, getproperty, getproperties

I want to use `transition` and `transform` to make a slider. I use the `getPropertyValue` to check the current slide. It works fine in Chrome, but in the IE9 it shows an error: `TypeError: Cannot read property '0' of null` (I marked the line with **)

the `Javascript` code:

```
var slider = container.querySelector("ul");   

function getCurrSliderIndex() {
            var text = slider.style.getPropertyValue("transform");
            console.log(text);
            var pattern = /[0-9]+/;
            **var match = pattern.exec(text)[0];**
            var intValue = parseInt(match) / width - 1;
            return intValue;
        }
```

the `HTML` code:

```
<ul id="primary-slider" class=" iuiSlider fix" style="width: 3794px; height: 271px; transform: translateX(-1084px);">
  <li>some content</li>
  <li>some content</li>
  <li>some content</li>
...
</ul>
```

Comment: What does your `console.log(text);` output?

Comment: Hi, @blex it output `translateX(-1084px)` in Chrome, the value of the `transform` in string type. but nothing in IE9

Comment: Does [**this demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/2L6fqne1/) work in IE9 (I can't test it now)? If it does, try including this code in yours.

Comment: @blex yes! it does! I awared the problem is IE9 doesn't support `transform`, it requires the `-ms-`. But now the problem is how can I use the `setProperty`. Can I just write `slider.style.setProperty("transform", "translateX(" + (-1 - nextSliderIndex) * width + "px)");`
   `slider.style.setProperty("-ms-transform", "translateX(" + (-1 - nextSliderIndex) * width + "px)");`?

Comment: At first sight, it should work, but if you use properties that need a prefix a lot in your code, you might want to create a function that automatically does it. For example, create a `setPrefixedProperty()` and a `getPrefixedProperty()` function to handle this, in order to have a shorter and cleaner main script.

Comment: @blex thank you very much. I will try it

Comment: I gave it a try: http://jsfiddle.net/2achxL4d/

Comment: @blex it works great. :) thanks a lot

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem here is not really the `getPropertyValue()` function, which is supported in IE9+.

But CSS properties like `transform` need vendor prefixes to work across browsers. To make it easier, you could create functions that handle them so you don't have to:

```js
/* Declare these functions to handle the prefixes */

Object.prototype.setPrefixedProperty = function(prop, value){
    this.setProperty(prop, value);
    this.setProperty('-moz-' + prop, value);
    this.setProperty('-webkit-' + prop, value);
    this.setProperty('-ms-' + prop, value);
    this.setProperty('-o-' + prop, value);
};

Object.prototype.getPrefixedProperty = function(prop){
    return this.getPropertyValue(prop)
        || this.getPropertyValue('-moz-' + prop)
        || this.getPropertyValue('-webkit-' + prop)
        || this.getPropertyValue('-ms-' + prop)
        || this.getPropertyValue('-o-' + prop);
};

/* Use them like so: */

var slider = document.querySelector('div');

slider.style.setPrefixedProperty('transform', 'translateX(-1084px)');

var text = slider.style.getPrefixedProperty('transform');

alert(text);
```

```html
<p>This demo should alert "translateX(-1084px)".</p>
<div></div>
```

Comment: this works great. But there's a new problem. the `transform` do changed correctly, but the slide doesn't changed until the mouse enters or leaves the slide. you could check it at http://dev.photoworld.com.cn/ . I use `transition` to control the animation which doesn't be supported in IE9. I thought it should slide immediately in IE9 but it doesn't.

Comment: @BrickYang Oh, I cannot access the URL ([not found, or access denied from outside of China?](http://downforeveryoneorjustme.com/http://dev.photoworld.com.cn/)), is there another address where this can be accessed, or could you create a [JS Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/) that reproduces the problem?

Comment: sorry. I tried JS Fiddle but cannot handle it(I create a lot of elements and stylesheet in JS, not sure if it's the problem). Could you try http://115.28.2.132/www/ ?

Comment: @BrickYang I cannot see the images, but I see the structure, and it seems to be working in Chrome and IE11, right? I can't test IE9 right now, but I'll have some time to do it tomorrow.

Comment: yes it woks in Chrome(didn't test IE11 but I think it should be fine). In IE9 the property changed correctly(if you can see the dots at the bottom of the slider, you can find it changed correctly too), but the images don't "fresh" until move mouse over them. thanks again.